# Há alguma técnica para aplicar manutenção no código?

Tags: java, refatoração

Além de aplicar a alta coesão e baixo acoplamento, como lidar com códigos como esse? Podem ser até legíveis mas esse excesso de operadores lógicos, não vejo ser possível refatorar nem com `switch-case`.

```
                        if (!entry.isDirectory()
                        && !entry.getName().startsWith("__MACOSX/")
                        && !entry.getName().startsWith("_images/")
                        && !entry.getName().contains("/_images")
                        && !entry.getName().contains("/._")
                        && !entry.getName().contains("/_img")
                        && !entry.getName().contains("/imgs")
                        && !entry.getName().contains("/_old")) {
                    String filename = Util.buildFilename(nome);
                    filenameMap.put(filename, nome);

                    if (!nome.startsWith("[.]")
                            && (nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".swf")
                            || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")
                            || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || nome
                            .toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg"))) {
                        files.add(dest + nome);
                    }

                    File destFile = FileUtils.getFile(dest, filename);

                    copyInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry),
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile)));
                }
```

SonarQube

> Expressions should not be too complex
>
> The complexity of an expression is defined by the number of &&, || and
>   condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse operators it contains. A single
>   expression's complexity should not become too high to keep the code
>   readable.

Comment: Creio que lhe ajudaria a ter respostas mais bem colocadas se você incluisse na sua pergunta qual é a intenção (isto é, a função) deste trecho de código. Se você deseja "filtrar" padrões de arquivos, talvez a melhor resposta seja realmente uma combinação das duas que você já tem: criar uma função que receba o arquivo e uma lista de padrões a serem ignorados, e então usar expressões regulares para verificar o arquivo para cada padrão da lista.

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso pouca coisa pode ser feita. Estes analisadores de código não distinguem a intenção. O que pode melhorar um pouco é criar a condição em um método e no `if` apenas chamar o método que retornará um booleano. Não sei se vai satisfazer totalmente o analisador ou vai apenas mudar a reclamação de lugar, mas deixa o código mais semântico.

De fato o `switch` não faria sentido aí.

A outra resposta dá uma solução mas tem uma brincadeira que diz que quando você tenta solucionar um problema com `RegEx` você passa ter dois problemas. Isto tem lá seu fundo de verdade, ainda que talvez não seja o caso para o que você está fazendo especificamente.

Eu particularmente criaria uma função genérica que faça a verificação passando uma lista de textos. Mas pode tentar com `RegEx` para ver se gosta da solução.

Note que pode ser que a lógica não apresente o resultado desejado em todas as situações. Como não conheço a exata situação mas me parece que há chance de produzir falsos positivos em alguns casos onde os *path* pode estar em uma ordem diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Você está basicamente fazendo comparações de Strings pra definir o fluxo do código. Expressões regulares podem deixar seu código mais limpo.

[Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

[Java Regex - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Entretanto, expressões regulares podem se tornar confusas de ler e difíceis de rastrear durante o debug. Recomendo isolar o método que faz o teste e implementar um bom teste unitário para validá-lo.

Um pouco de código pra te inspirar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String regularExpression =
            "(" + 
            "(__MACOSX/.*)" +
            "|(_images/.*)" +
            "|(.*/_images.*)" +
            "|(.*/\\._.*)" +
            "|(.*/_img*)" +
            "|(.*/imgs*)" +
            "|(.*/_old*)" +
            ")";

    System.out.println("__MACOSX/".matches(regularExpression));
    System.out.println("_images/".matches(regularExpression));
    System.out.println("/_images".matches(regularExpression));
    System.out.println("/._".matches(regularExpression));
    System.out.println("/_img".matches(regularExpression));
    System.out.println("/imgs".matches(regularExpression));
    System.out.println("/_old".matches(regularExpression));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma técnica padrão infelizmente, porém existem sim várias técnicas, eu não sei se esta é o melhor, porém é algo que podemos aplicar (baseado em [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27846000/1518921)) seria criar uma variável e testando uma condição de cada vez, por exemplo:

```
boolean returnValue;

returnValue = !entry.isDirectory();
returnValue &= !entry.getName().startsWith("__MACOSX/");
returnValue &= !entry.getName().startsWith("_images/");
returnValue &= !entry.getName().contains("/_images");
returnValue &= !entry.getName().contains("/._");
returnValue &= !entry.getName().contains("/_img");
returnValue &= !entry.getName().contains("/imgs");
returnValue &= !entry.getName().contains("/_old");

if (returnValue) {
    String filename = Util.buildFilename(nome);
...
```

Estes operadores são chamados de  bitwise/bit-a-bit:

- `&` (`AND`) - Exemplo: `a & b` - retorna `true` se `a` e `b` forem ambos `true`. Senão retorna false. Ambas expressões a e b são sempre avaliadas.
- `|`  (`OR`)  - Exemplo: a | b - retorna `true` se `a` ou `b` for `true`. Senão retorna `false`. Ambas expressões `a` e `b` são sempre avaliadas.
- `^` (`OR` exclusivo) - Exemplo: `a ^ b` - retorna `true` se `a` for `true` e `b` for false ou vice-versa. Senão retorna `false`

Você também pode fazer uma verificação linha por linha reaproveitando o `returnValue`:

```
boolean returnValue;

returnValue = !entry.isDirectory();
returnValue = returnValue &&!entry.getName().startsWith("__MACOSX/");
returnValue = returnValue &&!entry.getName().startsWith("_images/");
returnValue = returnValue &&!entry.getName().contains("/_images");
returnValue = returnValue &&!entry.getName().contains("/._");
returnValue = returnValue &&!entry.getName().contains("/_img");
returnValue = returnValue &&!entry.getName().contains("/imgs");
returnValue = returnValue &&!entry.getName().contains("/_old");

if (returnValue) {
    String filename = Util.buildFilename(nome);
...
```

Ao meu ver este segundo exemplo é mais fácil de fazer a manutenção.